# Code Errors in libGDX android and html folders in ecplise

Tags: java, android, html, libgdx

So I finally installed JDK 8 64bit with loads of hassles, install the gdx-setup.jar and generated my project with no problem. When I import my project in ecplise, The Android and HTML folders show an X. (Meaing there is an error in the code). However, Desktop, IOS and Core are fine.

What am I doing wrong here? (I tried regenrating the project to no avail.)

Im not too woried about HTML as its just a bonus feature for me. Im more worried about Android. IM using a 64bit JDK 1.8, ecplise IDE 64bit for java and on a 64 bit OS.

The Android SDK I used was the one used by Android Studio (Is this the problem ?)

Here is one error message:

```
The project was not built since its build path is incomplete.Cannot find the class file for com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint . Fix the build path then try building this project   firstGdxGame-html   Unknown Java Problem
```

And another similar one:

```
The project was not built since its build path is incomplete.Cannot find the class file for android.os.handler. Fix the build path then try building this project   firstGdxGame-html   Unknown Java Problem
```

Here is an image of the errors (Android and HTML folders)
[image: Screenshot of Errors]

Help?

Comment: why Eclipse ? Give a chance to Android Studio

Comment: You need to provide more information than the screenshot. According to the error message you have problems with your build path, so eclipse can't locate the libraries. Goto the related project settings and see what eclipse complains about.

Comment: When I used Eclipse with LibGDX I would say for every five hours of actual progress on my games and apps, I'd spend an hour fighting build issues like this. Do yourself a huge favor and use Android Studio or IDEA. With Eclipse, Gradle projects feel like a hacked-in afterthought that you have to support with wonky third-party plugins. In IDEA, they just work. The past few years, Android's philosophy has changed more to marching forward with progress, forcing you to use newer build systems and breaking old projects. This pain is magnified if your are using an unsupported IDE.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thanks, I will try IDEA. Its been such a pain using ecplise.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Another libGDX question. Do I need ANY extra sort of plugins for libGDX to work in IDEA?

Comment: If you are working with Android, I think it's worth it to just install Android Studio and use that. I have had issues in the past where some new Android Build Tools update breaks something and they fix it right away in Andtoid Studio but it takes a month to show up in IDEA. But of course I don't figure that out until I've spent an hour troubleshooting it. Sometimes you don't have the option of using out of date Android build tools because you need the latest in order to use Google services like ads or in-app purchases.

Comment: Otherwise, I don't think you technically need any plugins for IDEA besides the Android plugin that it comes with by default.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Android is not my main goal, I will do Desktop projects first and maybe some Android and IOS after.

Comment: If you are trying to use the latest Android Build Tools, and if you are using a recent JDK version, you need to update the Gradle wrapper version to at least 5.1.1. The LibGDX Setup project generator defaults to a very old Gradle version that is incompatible with newer versions of the JDK. And you will also need to update all the "compile" keywords in your build.gradle files to "implementation". And finally there is a line where "sourceDir" needs to be changed to "sourceDirs". Gradle will complain and link to that line for you to fix it.

Comment: Then IDEA with no plugins should be fine. You might want to comment out the "Android" module from gradle.properties so you don't have to deal with any build issues in the meantime. But what I said in my last comment still applies if you are using a recent JDK.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I have JDK 8 installed, beacuse libGDX dosent work wih JDK 12 in my case. Also, when I start IDEA, I cannot the desktop, core, android, ios folders. Are there any reported issues with JDK 12 and libGDX?

Comment: @Tenfour04 Never mind the folders not showing up, I Overwrite them on accident

Comment: Just the issues I mentioned how to fix above. Not sure what issue you're describing. Might need a screenshot.

Comment: @Tenfour04 How would I update the default gradle to 5.1.1?

Comment: Open `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` and change the file name at the very end to gradle-5.1.1-all.zip. Then refresh the gradle project (open gradle tab at very right of screen and click the refresh button).

Comment: @Tenfour04 And 5.1.1 will not work with JDK 8 x64?

Comment: I think that should work fine. The compatibility problem is using old Gradle versions with new JDK versions. I don't know the exact cutoff. But since you are using JDK 8, and not using Android, you don't need to fool with the gradle version at all. I updated my Gradle version so I could use JDK 12, because old JDK's are a big hassle to install as you already have discovered. Using the new JDK hasn't caused me any issues besides needing to update the gradle version. You can still target Java 7 or 8 while building with JDK 12.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thanks! I updated gradle version to 5.1.1 and fixed the issues. Thank you very much for your time! I will be very much deleting ecplise. Thanks for suggesting IDEA